# Coloring area under the curve in achartengine in android

Tags: java, android, charts, android-canvas, android-view

how to  color the area under the curve in worm chart line of [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org) for android.[image]

Comment: What kind of chart is this ?

Comment: can you post the code for creating the chart ? you can use BarChart for this so that the inside portion will be colored by default

Comment: Do you any thing about achartengin!!!!!!!

Comment: I don't know in details but I'm pretty sure that BarChart will be there for every chart engines because it is a so common chart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be as simple as:

```
FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);
fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
seriesRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

Comment: The method addFillOutsideLine(XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine) is undefined for the type XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.
also Cannot cast from XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to XYSeriesRenderer.
I am using XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.

Comment: Use the latest version. It is available here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/

Comment: renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0) will return you a SimpleSeriesRenderer that you can cast to XYSeriesRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

FillOutsideLine fill = new FillOutsideLine(FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);

fill.setColor(Color.BLUE);

seriesRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to answer in words and not only in code. And since you answer so late, how does your answer differ from the one that was already posted by Dan?