# Color area under line on graph in AChartEngine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am trying to fill out the area under my linegraph on a multiple series render. I have all the lines showing with the data just fine, I am just not getting how to fill the space from 0 up to the graph line. Here is my code for the graph:

```
        TempSeries = new TimeSeries("Temperature");
        SnowDepthSeries = new TimeSeries("Snow Depth");
        SWESeries = new TimeSeries("Snow Water Equivalent");

        mDataset.addSeries(TempSeries);
        mDataset.addSeries(SnowDepthSeries);
        mDataset.addSeries(SWESeries);

        TempRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        SnowDepthRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        SWERenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();

        SWERenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 255, 255));
        SWERenderer.setLineWidth(5f);

        SnowDepthRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        SnowDepthRenderer.setLineWidth(5f);

        TempRenderer.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
        TempRenderer.setLineWidth(5f);

        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(TempRenderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(SnowDepthRenderer);
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(SWERenderer);

        mRenderer.setLegendHeight(100);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle(chartTitle);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(30);
        mRenderer.setXTitle("\n\n\n\n\n72 Hours");
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(89, 71, 61));
        mRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.rgb(89, 71, 61));
```

I have tried to fill below like so without success ([Coloring area under the curve in achartengine in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652497/coloring-area-under-the-curve-in-achartengine-in-android)):

```
FillOutsideLine fill = FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_BELOW;
        fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        TempRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

I tried casting to no effect also:

```
FillOutsideLine fill = (XYSeriesRenderer) FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_BELOW;
        fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        TempRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

I'd like to add color just below each of my lines. I have 3 series on this one graph. 
[image: How to Shade This Area?]
Using: AChartEngine 1.1.0.jar, Android 4.3.x, Eclipse (Android Developer)

Comment: You cannot do that with the ACE out of the box. However, you can checkout the code and add the feature you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dan. I'll check it out. Maybe I can help out :)

Comment: It sounds like a good plan.

Comment: @Dan: what is this doing:  switch (fill.getType()) {
        case BOUNDS_ALL:
          referencePoint = yAxisValue;
          break;
        case BOUNDS_BELOW:
          referencePoint = yAxisValue;
          break;
        case BOUNDS_ABOVE:
          referencePoint = yAxisValue;
          break;
        case BELOW:
          referencePoint = canvas.getHeight();
          break;
        case ABOVE:
          referencePoint = 0;
          break;
        default:

Comment: It's probably the top point of the fill area.

Comment: Have you tried using BOUNDS_ABOVE instead of BOUNDS_BELOW?
That was what gave me the effect I wanted...

Comment: Yes, I tried that... it wasn't formatting correctly. I haven't been able to get back to my project in a while, hence no updates here... I'll check that again. Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fill = FillOutsideLine.Type.BELOW;
fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
TempRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine fill = new XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine(XYSeriesRenderer.FillOutsideLine.Type.BOUNDS_ALL);
fill.setColor(Color.GREEN);
TempRenderer.addFillOutsideLine(fill);
```